# Problems with div fitting browser window

Tags: css, html, cross-browser

I think my last question was misunderstood. I have pasted below, the HTML of the page I am having troubles with, but you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/wCZYU/6/

Basically I would like a fixed header (pageHeader) and a colored div that fills the browser window, NOT the entire page background. I then would like a div under this that the user will be required to scroll to see

```
<header class="pageHeader">
<div class="setWidth">
<div class="navMain">
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
<a href="portfolio.php">Work</a>
<a href="/blog">Blog</a>
<a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>
</header>
<div class="secFill">i want to be below the navigation</div>
<div class="content">i want to be below secFill</div>
```

This is the image that I posted earlier that I want it to look like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZgMb.png

The navigation must be fixed and compatible in ie7/8.

Thanks alot (again)

Comment: You'll need something besides CSS (I'd suggest jQuery), which can find the size of the browser window (after all, you don't know what the size of the user's browser window will be), then modify the css attributes on .secFill to match the browser window size.

Comment: I did something similar with http://wearepopular.tv/ .... I have some js that just detects the browser height and makes the image that height. You could definitely do the same with your div, unless Tim's solution works in all browsers, then i'd say do that!

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly, you just need to define .secFill as `height:100%`.

```
.secFill { 
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wCZYU/7/

Comment: That looks good, however the text isn't below the navigation which is where i wanted it, which is actually behind the navigation at the moment. I'm trying to avoid margin/padding, but I guess it's hard to do so.

Comment: Just add `padding-top` to the `.secFill` to simulate that. Why are you trying to avoid padding and margin? This is exactly why padding and margin exist.

Comment: With the fixed element out of the flow, something has to consume the height it otherwise would. Padding, Margin, or another Element.

Comment: Ok I see, I've added padding, but the secFill div moves down, anything to resolve that? http://jsfiddle.net/wCZYU/8/

Comment: You can use `calc()` to calculate the height of the section. http://jsfiddle.net/wCZYU/9/ `height:calc(100% - 60px);`